# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding in windows

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

When I'm doing the building the maven project it is throwing the below error. I checked all my code no where \ or \u present in code. While a lot of answers and resources point out errors in / vs , I want to mention that I have no local changes and this repo just works fine for others in my team. It worked fine for me as well before.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert (Properties.java:667)
    at java.util.Properties.load0 (Properties.java:456)
    at java.util.Properties.load (Properties.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.TrackingFileManager.read (TrackingFileManager.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.read (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkMetadata (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion (DefaultVersionResolver.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:204)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I have already tried the following:

1. Reinstalled java on my mac
2. Reinstalled maven Tried to invalidate
3. Tried to invalidate cache and restart IntelliJ multiple times.

Can some please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one of my third party library is having property file inside .m2/repository folder.

That property file is causing the issue. So, I fixed the issue by deleting .m2/repository folder and updating the library with proper syntax.

Comment: If they do things like that, you might want to switch to another library

Comment: Yaa correct, I removed it from my pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on the line of code: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Malformed \uxxxx encoding.") in Properties.java:667,

build the project in debug mode
when the debugger stops at breakpoint, search the stack for the value of the input variable that has the error. it will point to the problematic file that can be deleted/corrected

in my case it was the code in Properties.class:

```
public synchronized void load(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
    load0(new LineReader(inStream));
}
```

In a variable inStream I find a problem filename and delete it.
This solved the problem

Comment: This helped point me in the right direction! Here are the exact steps I followed using IntelliJ IDEA: (1) Open `java.util.Properties` and search for `"Malformed `. Add a breakpoint to that statement (for me, line 573). (2) Open the Maven window, navigate to `Lifecycle`, right click the goal you want to run, and choose the `Debug` option. (3) When the debugger activates, under `this` there should be an entry like `Could not transfer metadata...` with the groupId and artifactId. (4) Find that folder in your local `.m2` repository and delete it. Lather, rinse, and repeat. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In your `.properties` file there should be a path property somewhere. Make sure that you use `/` and NOT `\` for this property.

And if you want to use `\` then you have to escape it this way `\\`.

Comment: Would you be able to attach the actual property file?